# Mocked UserManager doesn't really work as expected in tests

Tags: c#, testing, asp.net-core, mocking

I have some service that's responsible for changing user password while using `UserManager` and everything works fine, but when I want to write some tests, then it starts failing at method `CheckPassword`, which basically checks if `current (old password)` is correct

```
myService:
public async bool TryChangePassword(User user, string OldPassword, string NewPassword)
{
    (...)

    // it returns false
    var checkOldPassword = await _userManager.CheckPasswordAsync(user, OldPassword);

    if (!checkOldPassword)
    {
        return false;
    }

    var token = await _userManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(user);

    var result = await _userManager.ResetPasswordAsync(user, token, NewPassword);

    return result.Succeeded;
}

myTests:

private readonly UserManager<User> _userManager;

[Fact]
public void password_change_attempt_1()
{
    var service = new myService(_context, _userManager);

    var user = new User("john");

    var register = _userManager.CreateAsync(user, "123456");

    _context.SaveChanges();

    Assert.True(_context.Users.Any());

    var result = service.TryChangePassword(user, "123456", "newPassword");
}
```

but for some reason it fails at:

> var checkOldPassword = await _userManager.CheckPasswordAsync(user, OldPassword);

it returns false, but as you can see, provided password is correct, probably there's something wrong with mocking user manager

Here's how do I create mock of `UserManager` in `Tests'` constructor

```
public Tests()
{
    var o = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<Context>();
    o.UseInMemoryDatabase(Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
    _context = new Context(o.Options);
    _context.Database.EnsureCreated();

    var userStore = new MockUserStore(_context);
    _userManager = new MockUserManager(userStore,
                        new Mock<IOptions<IdentityOptions>>().Object,
                        new Mock<IPasswordHasher<User>>().Object,
                        new IUserValidator<User>[0],
                        new IPasswordValidator<User>[0],
                        new Mock<ILookupNormalizer>().Object,
                        new Mock<IdentityErrorDescriber>().Object,
                        new Mock<IServiceProvider>().Object,
                        new Mock<ILogger<UserManager<User>>>().Object);
}

public class MockUserManager : UserManager<User>
{
    public MockUserManager(IUserStore<User> store, IOptions<IdentityOptions> optionsAccessor,
     IPasswordHasher<User> passwordHasher, IEnumerable<IUserValidator<User>> userValidators,
      IEnumerable<IPasswordValidator<User>> passwordValidators, ILookupNormalizer keyNormalizer,
       IdentityErrorDescriber errors, IServiceProvider services, ILogger<UserManager<User>> logger)
        : base(store, optionsAccessor, passwordHasher, userValidators, passwordValidators, keyNormalizer, errors, services, logger)
    {
    }

    public override Task<IdentityResult> CreateAsync(User user)
    {
        this.Store.CreateAsync(user, new CancellationToken());
        return Task.FromResult(IdentityResult.Success);
    }
}
public class MockUserStore : IUserStore<User>, IUserPasswordStore<User>
{
    public readonly Context _ctx;

    public MockUserStore(Context ctx)
    {
        _ctx = ctx;
    }
    public Task<IdentityResult> CreateAsync(User user, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        _ctx.Users.Add(user);

        return Task.FromResult(IdentityResult.Success);
    }

    public Task<IdentityResult> DeleteAsync(User user, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public Task<User> FindByIdAsync(string userId, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public Task<User> FindByNameAsync(string normalizedUserName, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public Task<string> GetNormalizedUserNameAsync(User user, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public Task<string> GetPasswordHashAsync(User user, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return Task.FromResult<string>(user.PasswordHash);
    }

    public Task<string> GetUserIdAsync(User user, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return Task.FromResult<string>(user.Id);
    }

    public Task<string> GetUserNameAsync(User user, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public Task<bool> HasPasswordAsync(User user, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return Task.FromResult<bool>(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(user.PasswordHash));
    }

    public Task SetNormalizedUserNameAsync(User user, string normalizedName, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public Task SetPasswordHashAsync(User user, string passwordHash, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        user.PasswordHash = passwordHash;
        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }

    public Task SetUserNameAsync(User user, string userName, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public Task<IdentityResult> UpdateAsync(User user, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

I suppose it can be fixed here:

```
public Task<IdentityResult> CreateAsync(User user, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    _ctx.Users.Add(user);

    return Task.FromResult(IdentityResult.Success);
}
```

by adding something like

```
user.PasswordHash = generateHash(password)
```

but how can I know how many iterations do ASP.NET Core Identity does use?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/consumer-apis/password-hashing?view=aspnetcore-2.2

```
string hashed = Convert.ToBase64String(KeyDerivation.Pbkdf2(
    password: password,
    salt: salt,
    prf: KeyDerivationPrf.HMACSHA1,
    iterationCount: 10000,
    numBytesRequested: 256 / 8));
```

Comment: When you say "fails" what's the failure? Exception?

Comment: @JamieRees "it returns false, but as you can see, provided password is correct, probably there's something wrong with mocking user manager"

Comment: Why are you creating a custom `UserManager` implementation? You've already mocked all the dependencies, so just new up `UserManager<TUser>` directly. Creating a custom implementation introduces more untested code, that could fail your other tests, even though there's nothing actually wrong with those tests. The point is to use real implementations whenever possible.

Answer (score 0):

You should always try to avoid using so deep mocks. 
Hide concrete implementation with your own interface.

```
public interface IMyUserManager
{
    Task<bool> CheckPasswordAsync(User user, string oldPassword);
    Task<string> GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(User user);        
    Task<IdentityResult> ResetPasswordAsync(User user, string token, string 
        newPassword);
    }
}
```

Secondly, implement this interface with built-it UserManager

```
public class MyUserManager : IMyUserManager 
{
    private readonly UserManager<User> _userManager;

    public MyUserManager(UserManager<User> userManager)
    {
        if (userManager is null)
        {
           throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(userManager));
        }
        _userManager = userManager;
    }

    public Task<bool> CheckPasswordAsync(User user, string oldPassword)
    {
        return _userManager.CheckPasswordAsync(user, oldPassword);
    }

    public Task<string> GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(User user)
    {
        return _userManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(user);
    }

    public Task<IdentityResult> ResetPasswordAsync(User user, string token, 
        string newPassword)
    {
        return _userManager.ResetPasswordAsync(user, token, newPassword);
    }
}
```

Then, rewrite your service

```
        private readonly IMyUserManager _userManager;

        public MyService(IMyUserManager userManager)
        {
            _userManager = userManager;
        }
        public async Task<bool> TryChangePassword(User user, string OldPassword, string NewPassword)
        {
            // it returns false
            var checkOldPassword = await _userManager.CheckPasswordAsync(user, OldPassword);

            if (!checkOldPassword)
            {
                return false;
            }

            var token = await _userManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(user);

            var result = await _userManager.ResetPasswordAsync(user, token, NewPassword);

            return result.Succeeded;
```

Finally, write test cases as simple as possible. People around you never want to go to the implementation of subclasses when fix tests

```
[Fact]
        public async Task password_change_attempt_1()
        {
            var mock = new Mock<IMyUserManager>();
            MyService myService = new MyService(mock.Object);
            mock.Setup(x => x.CheckPasswordAsync(It.IsAny<User>(), It.IsAny<string>()))
                .Returns(Task.FromResult(true));
            mock.Setup(x => x.ResetPasswordAsync(It.IsAny<User>(), It.IsAny<string>(),
                It.IsAny<string>()))
                .Returns(Task.FromResult(IdentityResult.Success));

            var result =
                await myService
                    .TryChangePassword(new User { Name = "Name", }, "OldPassword", "NewPassword");

            Assert.Equal(result, true);
        }
```